# Will a Deck Get Damaged if it Rains Between Cleaning it and Sealing it?

Tags: deck, sealing, water-damage

I'm looking to clean and seal my deck as per [this process](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/27330/31536), basically:

1. Clean it
2. Allow a week for the deck to dry
3. Apply sealant

The way I am thinking of timing it, there's a chance it may rain between 1 and 3. So obviously, I'd want to wait another week after any rain for the deck to dry, but if I am trying to plan when to clean my deck, should I try to avoid any rain between 1 and 3? Will rain on a freshly cleaned (but not sealed) deck cause damage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rain really will not hurt unless the deck is wet when you seal it. If wet when sealed depending on the type of sealer it may be ok (water based) or with oil based it will not adhere as well.